# New S3 bucket created hosting static website: access denied / 403 forbidden error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Created a new bucket in S3. 
Created a hosted zone in Route 53 service, added the domain(buzzindia.biz)
Created the bucket policy, [bucket policy can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu6hv.png)

Uploaded a index.html file to the bucket
Able to access the index file from [this url](http://buzzindia.biz.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html) 
but **unable to access from the domain name in the browser** (buzzindia.biz),getting 403 forbidden error

> 403 Forbidden
>
> ```
> Code: AccessDenied
> Message: Access Denied
> RequestId: 4BECED9C1264762B
> HostId: 7LooXNEnXbVJ7rVPRaakzfmmYNKzgsygBS4EiBnez85w+m4//dtmZPv7jsdKb0z1QTKSeFmWErQ=
> ```

Also, we changed the nameservers for this domain (buzzindia.biz) to the following

NS-1373.AWSDNS-43.ORG 
NS-1927.AWSDNS-48.CO.UK 
NS-476.AWSDNS-59.COM 
NS-631.AWSDNS-14.NET

Kindly help us in access our website from the domain name url i.e buzzindia.biz